# How do I backup my website homescreen shortcuts?

Tags: file-system, home-screen-shortcuts, home-screen, bookmarks, home-screen-folders

I have many websites which I constantly access thru my phone, but they aren't bookmarked on Google, they're just added to my homescreen as a web shortcut.

Of course Windows is something else entirely, but I could just go to Desktop folder and copy everything *.lnk, right? Thing is, now I'm migrating phones. I already migrated all apps I wanted to keep. I feel there should be an equivalent easy way to do this, even without an app. Is there?

Answer (score 1):

Everything on the home-screen is organized by the configured "launcher" app. Therefore it depends on the used launcher.

Some advanced launchers include a functionality to export the complete launcher configuration including web-links and all the other launcher icons.

The default launcher is usually modified by the manufacturer hence it is difficult to say what it supports.

As a fallback mechanism you can try to create an backup of the launcher via Android Debug Bridge (`adb`). However this requires to

1. Enable Developer menu
2. Activate in the Developer Menu the Android Debug Bridge
3. Connect your Android smartphone to your PC via an appropriate USB cable
4. Install the ADB drivers and ADB on your PC
5. Identify the package name of the used launcher
6. Perform the backup on the command-line/terminal of your PC via `adb backup <packagename of launcher app> launcher-backup.ab`.
7. Check the created file `launcher-backup.ab` if it is larger than a few kilobytes then the chance if good that the backup was successful

On the new device (or after a factory reset) you have to more or less perform the same steps. Just execute `adb restore launcher-backup.ab` as the last step.

Comment: I would like to add that if the browser through which the shortcuts were originally created is no longer installed and *enabled* in the target device the shortcuts won't be restored AFAIK. I had once created a demo web shortcut through Chrome. I disable Chrome and shortcut was gone even though Firefox was my default browser all the time. I enabled Chrome and the shortcut didn't come back.