# How to transfer Chrome start screen links to a new mobile phone?

Tags: samsung, chrome-for-android, data-transfer, home-screen-shortcuts, hyperlinks

On my old mobile phone (Samsung, Android 10) on the desktop, I have many folders with website links (you know, the ones you can create in Chrome when you select the "..." menu and then choose "Add to start screen").

Now I got a new mobile phone (Samsung, Android 12) and recognized that the Samsung Smart Switch tool doesn't copy the links from my old phone.

I know I could open every link separately and then bookmark it, but this is cumbersome and not an option I want to consider since I have collected many links over the years.

Is there a swift way to transfer the links from one phone to the other?

- or -

Do you know where on the phone the start screen links are stored?
(then maybe a tool like TotalCommander would be able to copy it via a WiFi connection).

Comment: Sorry! check this https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/224433/how-do-i-backup-my-website-homescreen-shortcuts

Comment: @M.A. - Thank you :-)    I will look into that.

Answer (score -1):

Save all you homescreen links as bookmarks, then follow instructions here to sync them on all your devices: https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/165139?co=GENIE.Platform%3DAndroid&oco=1 foll

Comment: The question asks about transferring home screen shortcut links. This answer won't work because they are handled by the home screen app, not Chrome.